# active admin display time only and text-alignment for default_actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

hi im working with active admin in ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2
i have two questions

1) im just wonder if its possible to change the alignment of the default actions in active admin(view,edit,destroy) im trying this but not working maybe im missing with the element i tried searching google but i cant find the right answer

```
.action{
  text-align: right;
}
```

2)in one of my index in active admin i have a time-start field i used a :time for database format which is currently(2012-04-05 16:59:00.000000) inside my database, so my index is showing (January 01, 2000 02:02) i want only the time to be show my index do is

```
index do 
    column "Guest Name", :name
    column "Service Type", :service
    column "Booked Date", :date
    column "Time Start", :timeStart
    column "Time End",:timeEnd
    column "Number of guest", :numGuest
    default_actions
  end
```

im think to do this but obviously it will not work

```
column "Time Start", :timeStart.strftime('%H:%M:%S:%p')
```

much appreciated for the help
thank you in advance more power to all

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your first question, but for displaying the time use a block like this:

```
column "Time Start" do |record|
  record.timeStart.strftime('%H:%M:%S:%p')
end
```